# Group_by / summarize by two variables within a function

Tags: r, dplyr, summarization

I would like to write a function that summarize the provided data by some specified criteria, in this case by age

The example data is a table of users' age and their stats.

```
df <- data.frame('Age'=rep(18:25,2), 'X1'=10:17, 'X2'=28:35,'X4'=22:29)
```

Next I define the output columns that are relevant for the analysis

```
output_columns <- c('Age', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3')
```

This function computes the basic the sum of X1. X2 and X3 grouped by age.

```
aggr <- function(data, criteria, output_columns){
  k <- data %>% .[, colnames(.) %in% output_columns] %>%
    group_by_(.dots = criteria) %>%
    #summarise_each(funs(count), age) %>%
    summarize_if(is.numeric, sum)
  return (k)
}
```

When I call it like this

```
> e <- aggr(df, "Age", output_columns)
> e
# A tibble: 8 x 3
    Age    X1    X2
  <int> <int> <int>
1    18    20    56
2    19    22    58
3    20    24    60
4    21    26    62
5    22    28    64
6    23    30    66
7    24    32    68
8    25    34    70
```

I want to have another column called *count* which shows the number of observations in each age group. Desired output  is

```
> desired
  Age X1 X2 count
1  18 20 56     2
2  19 22 58     2
3  20 24 60     2
4  21 26 62     2
5  22 28 64     2
6  23 30 66     2
7  24 32 68     2
8  25 34 70     2
```

I have tried different ways to do that, e.g. *tally(), summarize_each*
 etc. They all deliver wrong results.

I believe their should be an easy and simple way to do that.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you need `%>% group_by_at(criteria) %>% mutate(count = n())` added into your function

Comment: The last line in the pipeline could be replaced with: `{ cbind(summarize_if(., is.numeric, sum), summarize(., n = n())) }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're already summing all variables, you can just add a column of all `1`s before the summary function

```
aggr <- function(data, criteria, output_columns){ 
    data %>% 
      .[, colnames(.) %in% output_columns] %>%
      group_by_(.dots = criteria) %>%
      mutate(n = 1L) %>%
      summarize_if(is.numeric, sum)
}

# A tibble: 8 x 4
    Age    X1    X2     n
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    18    20    56     2
2    19    22    58     2
3    20    24    60     2
4    21    26    62     2
5    22    28    64     2
6    23    30    66     2
7    24    32    68     2
8    25    34    70     2
```

Comment: Is it better than my answer

Comment: that's clever, like it

Answer (score 1):

We could create the 'count' column before `summarise_if`

```
aggr<- function(data, criteria, output_columns){
                data %>% 
                   select(intersect(names(.), output_columns))%>%
                   group_by_at(criteria)%>%   
                   group_by(count = n(), add= TRUE) %>%                                
                   summarize_if(is.numeric,sum) %>%
                   select(setdiff(names(.), 'count'), count)                                     

    }




aggr(df,"Age",output_columns)
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   Age [8]
#    Age    X1    X2 count
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1    18    20    56     2
#2    19    22    58     2
#3    20    24    60     2
#4    21    26    62     2
#5    22    28    64     2
#6    23    30    66     2
#7    24    32    68     2
#8    25    34    70     2
```

Comment: @Ryan That is a good way.  I find that you posted an answer.  I like it

Comment: adding this line  _group_by(count = n(), add= TRUE)_ to my original function works just as fine. Can that lead to any mistake?

Comment: @esem After the summarise step, you can ungroup if you need any more transformations

Answer (score 1):

In base R you could do

```
aggr <- function(data, criteria, output_columns){
  ds <- data[, colnames(data) %in% output_columns]
  d <- aggregate(ds, by=list(criteria), function(x) c(sum(x), length(x)))
  "names<-"(do.call(data.frame, d)[, -c(2:3, 5)], c(names(ds), "n"))
}

> with(df, aggr(df, Age, output_columns))
  Age X1 X2 n
1  18 20 56 2
2  19 22 58 2
3  20 24 60 2
4  21 26 62 2
5  22 28 64 2
6  23 30 66 2
7  24 32 68 2
8  25 34 70 2
```